# Service injected in service is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have two services, where first is injected in second service, in this way:

**rule.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class RuleService {

    constructor(
        private _resourceService: ResourceService
    ){}

    someMethod(url: string) {
       this._resourceService.getData(url).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
       }
    }

}
```

**resource.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ResourceService {

   constructor(
       http: Http
   ) { }

   public getData(url?: string): Promise<T> {
       //some code
   }
}
```

**called service** *jQuery :(*

```
private run(input: any, a_parameters: any) {
$("select[name='" + a_parameters[0] + "']").change(function(e: any) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                let array: any[] = [];
                this._resourceService.getData(a_parameters[1]).then(() => {
                    let result: any;
...
```

but when I trying call *someMethod* from *RuleService*, I get this console error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getData' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of
>   undefined
>       at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/app.js:457:2), :210:39)
>       at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/polyfills.js:2304:2), :695:29)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/app.js:457:2), :208:20)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (http://cdn.execon.pl/resources/GRM/js/libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3:8066)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (http://cdn.execon.pl/resources/GRM/js/libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3:4767)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/polyfills.js:2304:2), :363:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/vendor.js:101:2), :3971:41)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/polyfills.js:2304:2), :362:36)
>       at Zone.runTask (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/polyfills.js:2304:2), :166:47)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at  (http://localhost:8099/polyfills.js:2304:2), :416:38)
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3064 next @
>   core.umd.js?e2a5:8041 schedulerFn @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3689
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM86162:223 SafeSubscriber.next @
>   VM86162:172 Subscriber._next @ VM86162:125 Subscriber.next @
>   VM86162:89 Subject.next @ VM86159:55 EventEmitter.emit @
>   core.umd.js?e2a5:3675 NgZone.triggerError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:4040
>   onHandleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:4001 ZoneDelegate.handleError @
>   zone.js?fad3:334 Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js?fad3:142
>   _loop_1 @ zone.js?fad3:540 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js?fad3:549 ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:420 ListPicker._handleMouseUp @
>   about:blank:540

Anyone can tell me, what I do wrong? How can I correct implement service in service?

Comment: Please add the code where you are calling `someMethod`

Comment: edited: Calling method

Comment: Thanks :) Then i see that you lose context

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its work. I can belive that i made that mistake. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use arrow function to retain `this`

```
$("select[name='" + a_parameters[0] + "']")
   .change((e: any) => { // <== arrow function instead of FE(function expression)
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            let array: any[] = [];
            this._resourceService.getData(a_parameters[1]).then(() => {
```